# Результаты MySQL-запроса, включающие нижнюю границу в BETWEEN

Tags: mysql, sql

Как выбрать все имена из таблицы, первая буква в которых удовлетворяет диапазону букв от **Р** до **Я**?

Составил такой запрос:

```
SELECT `name` FROM `table1` WHERE `name` BETWEEN 'Р' AND 'Я' ORDER BY `name`
```

В результирующей выборке отсутствуют результаты в которых `name` начинается с буквы **Я**, из чего я сделал вывод что `BETWEEN` выбирает значения, включая первую границу (Р), но не включая в результат вторую границу (Я).

Есть ли возможность составить такой запрос, чтобы имена с буквой Я тоже попали в результаты?

Нашёл такое решение:

> SELECT `name` FROM `table1` WHERE name`BETWEEN 'Р' AND 'Я' OR`
>   surname`LIKE 'Я%' ORDER BY`name`

Но если вдруг кто-то предложит более элегантное решение, буду рад изменить свой подход )

Comment: Вариант вида: SELECT `name` FROM `table1` WHERE `name` >= 'Р' AND `name` <= 'Я' ORDER BY `name` дает такой же результат, т.е. имена начинающиеся на букву Я не попадают в результаты

Comment: замечательно но как он поможет мне решить мою задачу с выборкой?

Comment: очевидно, вписав в запрос столько раз `LIKE 'БУКВА%' OR...`, сколько букв в нужном Вам диапазоне. насколько быстро это будет работать - вопрос.

Comment: `SELECT Name from test where name REGEXP "Сюда необходимо вставить регулярное выражение";` ввиду того что я не силен в регулярках, его предлагаю Вам составить самостоятельно

Comment: `WHERE name >= 'P' AND name < `... А какая буква после 'Я'? Никакой. Значит достаточно `name >= 'P'`. Для любой промежуточной буквы, например 'Ю', будет `name >= 'P' and name < 'Я'`, Надеюсь идея понятна.

Comment: Нет, идея не понятна, вы просто заменили <= Я на < Я,  а значит имена на букву Я не попадут под ваше условие, так как буква Я не меньше буквы Я.

Comment: `... BETWEEN 'Р' AND 'Яяяяя'`. Количество букв "Я" тут должно быть таким, чтобы никакое значение в поле `name` не начиналось с такого количества букв "Я". Если это реальные имена, то скорее всего достаточно будет всего двух — `'Яя'`.

Comment: @Enshtein чтобы Вам стало ясно составил ответ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

наверно, не всё поле надо сравнивать с буквой, а только первый символ:

[`substring(name,1,1)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring)

пример:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a64d/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t (n text);

insert into t values ('яблоки на снегу');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from t where n between 'р' and 'я'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a64d/1/0)**:

**Query 2**:

```
select * from t where substring(n,1,1) between 'р' and 'я'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a64d/1/1)**:

```
|               n |
|-----------------|
| яблоки на снегу |
```

Comment: блин так просто, я с *регуляркой* посоветовал

Answer (score 5):

Для особо догадливых, на вопросы смотрящих ширше, вникающих глубже.

Воспользуемся тем, что нестрогие неравенства можно заменить на строгие.
`x between a and b` === `a <= x and x <= b` === `(a-1) < x and x < (b+1)`
Когда a == минимальному значению из всего допустимого множества значений, тогда сравнивать с ним никакого смысла не имеет, можем убрать неравенство c a, останется: `x <= b`
Тоже самое, когда b == максимальному значению: `a <= x`.

Исходя из выше сказанного и учитывая, что 'Я' - это последняя (т.е. максимальная) буква, условие из вопроса записывается в коротком виде: `'Р' <= name`
Запрос `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE 'Р' <= name` вопреки ожиданиям автора вопроса (как он понял мой коммент) всё-таки вернёт среди прочих и записи, в которых name начинается на букву 'Я'.

Для диапазона букв, не включающего последнюю букву 'Я', вместо верхнего предела берём следующую букву. Например вывести записи с именами, начинающимися с буквы от 'Р' до 'У' включительно. Следующая буква после буквы 'У' - это буква 'Ф'. Значит запрос будет выглядеть так: `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE 'Р' <= name AND name < 'Ф'`.

Comment: В отличии от subsrt в другом ответе, здесь Вы имеете все шансы задействовать индекс по полю name для ускорения работы запроса.

Answer (score 1):

При некоторых естественных предположениях:

```
SELECT `name` FROM `table1` WHERE `name` BETWEEN 'Р' AND 'Яя' ORDER BY `name`
```

А так без предположений :-)

```
    SELECT `name` FROM `table1` WHERE `name` BETWEEN 'Р' AND 
concat('Я',char(ascii('Я')+1)) ORDER BY `name`
```

Comment: Можете предполагать что угодно, но все ваши предположения коту под хвост, есть кот наступит на клавишу с буквой 'Я' и заполнит этой буквой всё поле. С вашим подходом надо сделать строку из букаф 'Я' длиной во всё поле.